# Select and display from MySQL table with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I want to select all the rows that have $name but it only shows the first row.  My table is like this

```
id 
name
password
email
```

Code :

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  data WHERE username ='$name'"));

print_r($result);
```

This is not working, it only shows the first row.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, you should look into mysqli or PDO.

Comment: did u checked that there are more than one entry for that username you have entered

Comment: yes sir,it fixed now $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username ='$name'");
$finalRes = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $finalRes[] = $result;
}
print_r($finalRes);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look errors:

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  data WHERE username = '$name'");
if (!$result) {
    var_export(mysql_error());
}
$data = [];
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
var_export($data);
```

and don't forget about sql-injections...

PDO:

```
<?php

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: '.$e->getMessage();
}
$name = 'yourName';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM  data WHERE username = :name');
$sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
if (!$sth->execute()) {
    throw new Exception($sth->errorInfo());
}
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_export($result);
```

Comment: 1) `"SELECT * FROM  data WHERE username = '$name'"` - it's a hole. Write this - it's bad practice... but problem not in this... 2) I suppose: if error occurs it should be processed... `var_export(mysql_error());`

Comment: ok,i will look more into how to prevent sql injection,for now  will just put var_export(mysql_error()); after each query.

Comment: I recommend to you use PDO!) And be sure that your user really exists at database)

Comment: alright PDO it is then,is it more secure or something?

Comment: yes! secure, performance, and much other... I added pdo example, looks almost the same, but more powerful...

Answer (score 1):

Better to use in this way

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username ='$name'");
$finalRes = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $finalRes[] = $result;
}
print_r($finalRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    $sql = "select * from data where username='$username'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {
   print_r($row);
   }
```

i have changed the code try this loop so that all the data will print,if not let us know

Comment: it still show me only first row //  Array ( [0] => 9 [id] => 9 [1] => anis [username] => anis [2] => test [email] => test [3] => test [password] => test )